# Error when trying to upload a Configuration Synchronization file

Tags: configuration

I want to create a local copy of a production website. I read that I could use Configuration Synchronization to copy some of the settings of the production website over to my local website. When I try to upload the exported .tar file from the production website to my local website, I get this error:

```
Could not extract the contents of the tar file. The error message is Invalid checksum for file "Y3drj:+uT}vG|59ooc&{C:BS1@/f/" : 65255 calculated, 0 expected
```

I'm using lando to host the website locally. I also had to delete some of the characters in the error message above because stack exchange wouldn't let me post them.

Comment: Seems like the .tar file is invalid. Either the exporter exported a faulty file, or the importer has a faulty parser. Test expanding the file on a different system to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is make few changes on settings.php file

$config_directories = array(

CONFIG_SYNC_DIRECTORY => 'sites/default/files',

);

On production sites, and if your account has permission to do so, it's a good idea to move the configuration sync directory outside of the webroot entirely. As your sync directory should be under version control, this means having your version control repository's root be one level higher than your webroot.  please check out more details at  https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/configuration-management/changing-the-storage-location-of-the-sync-directory